# How to Display Chinese character in java script and required field validators in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am not able to Display Chinese character in java script and required field validators.

Sample Code :

Resource File Key Msg_ExtraChar  -- 请输入

I have given Unicode value of Chinese character 请输入.

I have tried both option but not able to display.

```
var message = '<%=GetGlobalResourceObject("JavaScriptResource", "Msg_ExtraChar") %>'; 
  alert(message);
```

Please Help Me Out.

Answer (score 0):

The chinese characters probably can't be shown on the client because he had not installed language support for East Asian languages:

[image]

If the user has the files installed it should work.

You could use a modal popup dialog instead to allow the message to be shown even if the user does not have the files installed on his PC. There is an example of how to do that on this thread:

[how can make javascript alert() display japanese, chinese ..](http://www.progresstalk.com/showthread.php?52453-how-can-make-javascript-alert()-display-japanese-chinese-..)